# Ionic ion-input tag not rendering

Tags: ionic-framework

In my ionic app, the **ion-input** simply not render and I don't discovered why, yet.
For example, this code not render:

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" floating>Floating Label</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

Just the Floating Label appears, but the input effect not works and I cannot type anything.

What am I forgetting?

And more, the input style using the input tag **is in bold**, and in my own css am not changing the default style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing same issue. After googling, came to know this not work in Ionic 1. Ionic version 1 will not support ion-iput. This is supporting from Ionic 1 later versions like ionic 2,etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you did not create an [Ionic2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/) application !